# How does $this->load->view('view_name',$data,TRUE); works internally

Tags: codeigniter

I know what is the use of this method.

The third parameter of view method TRUE or FALSE how it works internally because want to make same method in core php which would be very usefull in core php. Not only in core in other framworks as well such as cake php too.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the main function that is called :

```
public function view($view, $vars = array(), $return = FALSE)
{
    return $this->_ci_load(array('_ci_view' => $view, '_ci_vars' => $this->_ci_object_to_array($vars), '_ci_return' => $return));
}
```

Now the first protected function _ci_load()

```
protected function _ci_load($_ci_data)
{
    // Set the default data variables
    foreach (array('_ci_view', '_ci_vars', '_ci_path', '_ci_return') as $_ci_val)
    {
        $$_ci_val = isset($_ci_data[$_ci_val]) ? $_ci_data[$_ci_val] : FALSE;
    }

    $file_exists = FALSE;

    // Set the path to the requested file
    if (is_string($_ci_path) && $_ci_path !== '')
    {
        $_ci_x = explode('/', $_ci_path);
        $_ci_file = end($_ci_x);
    }
    else
    {
        $_ci_ext = pathinfo($_ci_view, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        $_ci_file = ($_ci_ext === '') ? $_ci_view.'.php' : $_ci_view;

        foreach ($this->_ci_view_paths as $_ci_view_file => $cascade)
        {
            if (file_exists($_ci_view_file.$_ci_file))
            {
                $_ci_path = $_ci_view_file.$_ci_file;
                $file_exists = TRUE;
                break;
            }

            if ( ! $cascade)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if ( ! $file_exists && ! file_exists($_ci_path))
    {
        show_error('Unable to load the requested file: '.$_ci_file);
    }

    // This allows anything loaded using $this->load (views, files, etc.)
    // to become accessible from within the Controller and Model functions.
    $_ci_CI =& get_instance();
    foreach (get_object_vars($_ci_CI) as $_ci_key => $_ci_var)
    {
        if ( ! isset($this->$_ci_key))
        {
            $this->$_ci_key =& $_ci_CI->$_ci_key;
        }
    }

    /*
     * Extract and cache variables
     *
     * You can either set variables using the dedicated $this->load->vars()
     * function or via the second parameter of this function. We'll merge
     * the two types and cache them so that views that are embedded within
     * other views can have access to these variables.
     */
    if (is_array($_ci_vars))
    {
        foreach (array_keys($_ci_vars) as $key)
        {
            if (strncmp($key, '_ci_', 4) === 0)
            {
                unset($_ci_vars[$key]);
            }
        }

        $this->_ci_cached_vars = array_merge($this->_ci_cached_vars, $_ci_vars);
    }
    extract($this->_ci_cached_vars);

    /*
     * Buffer the output
     *
     * We buffer the output for two reasons:
     * 1. Speed. You get a significant speed boost.
     * 2. So that the final rendered template can be post-processed by
     *  the output class. Why do we need post processing? For one thing,
     *  in order to show the elapsed page load time. Unless we can
     *  intercept the content right before it's sent to the browser and
     *  then stop the timer it won't be accurate.
     */
    ob_start();

    // If the PHP installation does not support short tags we'll
    // do a little string replacement, changing the short tags
    // to standard PHP echo statements.
    if ( ! is_php('5.4') && ! ini_get('short_open_tag') && config_item('rewrite_short_tags') === TRUE)
    {
        echo eval('?>'.preg_replace('/;*\s*\?>/', '; ?>', str_replace('<?=', '<?php echo ', file_get_contents($_ci_path))));
    }
    else
    {
        include($_ci_path); // include() vs include_once() allows for multiple views with the same name
    }

    log_message('info', 'File loaded: '.$_ci_path);

    // Return the file data if requested
    if ($_ci_return === TRUE)
    {
        $buffer = ob_get_contents();
        @ob_end_clean();
        return $buffer;
    }

    /*
     * Flush the buffer... or buff the flusher?
     *
     * In order to permit views to be nested within
     * other views, we need to flush the content back out whenever
     * we are beyond the first level of output buffering so that
     * it can be seen and included properly by the first included
     * template and any subsequent ones. Oy!
     */
    if (ob_get_level() > $this->_ci_ob_level + 1)
    {
        ob_end_flush();
    }
    else
    {
        $_ci_CI->output->append_output(ob_get_contents());
        @ob_end_clean();
    }

    return $this;
}
```

second protected function _ci_object_to_array :

```
protected function _ci_object_to_array($object)
{
    return is_object($object) ? get_object_vars($object) : $object;
}
```

And that's it. If you know your php, you can easily make out what it does :) Cheers

Comment: Cool Awesome Stuff Aritra